# How can I include an hamletfile inside another using widgetFile?

Tags: haskell, yesod

For reusability, I want to re-use a widget inside another. For instance, the widget file `blogpost.hamlet` could contain how a post is displayed, and `blog.hamlet` could contain the full blog.

The following content of `blog.hamlet` does *not* work:

```
$forall post <- posts
    ^{widgetFile "blogpost")
```

So, what is the correct syntax to embed one widget inside another?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Hamlet syntax does not support embedding Template Haskell splices inside of it, which makes the code you're looking to do impossible. Instead, you need to create a helper function in Haskell, e.g.:

```
blogpost post = $(widgetFile "blogpost")
```

Then in blog.hamlet, you can have:

```
$forall post <- posts
    ^{blogpost post}
```

Comment: Does this not work inside defaultLayout? I have a scaffold site and I'm trying to do something very similar, and I get:
`Foundation.hs:73:27:
    Not in scope: ‘loginArea’
    In the splice:
      $(hamletFile "templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")`

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code, I can't know for certain, but that looks like a separate error. Namely, the identifier you're trying to use is not in scope.