# How to include one external hamlet file inside another?

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

My question is quite simple:

How can I include one external hamlet file into another external hamlet file?

Let's say I have a header or footer that's shared amongst every page, does it have to be 'assembled in haskell' like mentioned [here](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/widgets#60-x10), or can it just be referenced from another hamlet file, similar to the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) directive from Django?

Thanks

Comment: This might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791591/nested-widgets-with-widgetfile-in-yesod ?

Comment: @Hudon the hamlet files are going to work the same way the widget files are so it looks like a  duplicate to me.  I edited the title on the question you linked so that it is hopefully easier to search out using the various probably keywords.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed correct... I had seen that one, but it was not clear if it also applied to hamlet files... the new title makes it all-inclusive :)